# My service subscription only works in app component on angular9

Tags: angular

I amy angular 9 observables is not working on components other than app.component.

Here is my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class LoggedinService {

  constructor() { }

  private loggedinAnnouncedSource = new Subject<boolean>();
  // Observable string streams
  loggedinAnnounced$ = this.loggedinAnnouncedSource.asObservable();
  // Service message commands
  announceLoggedin(loggedin: boolean) {
    this.loggedinAnnouncedSource.next(loggedin);
  }

}
```

Here is hit works in app.component on init:

```
this.li_sub = this.loggedinService.loggedinAnnounced$.subscribe(
  isLoggedIn => {
    this.isLoggedIn = isLoggedIn;
    console.log('app isLoggedIn:',this.isLoggedIn);
}); //end this.li_sub
```

It fires and I get the below in the console:

```
 app isLoggedIn: true
```

I have another component that loads in onInit and it does not fire at all:

this.li_sub = this.loggedinService.loggedinAnnounced$.subscribe(

```
  isLoggedIn => {
    console.log('dashboard isLoggedIn:',this.isLoggedIn);
    this.isLoggedIn = isLoggedIn;

}); //end this.li_sub
```

As a result, I am not able to get this.isLoggedIn

Why will this not work?  There are no errors at all

UPDATE:

I used the below based on comment.  Why did this work?  I am coming from angular 7 where is worked.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable()
export class LoggedinServiceBehavior {

  constructor() { }

  private loggedinAnnouncedSourceB = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(null);
  // Observable string streams
  loggedinAnnouncedB$ = this.loggedinAnnouncedSourceB.asObservable();
  // Service message commands
  announceLoggedin(loggedin: boolean) {
    this.loggedinAnnouncedSourceB.next(loggedin);
  }

}
```

Comment: I guess that's because it had been fired before. You should be using BehaviorSubject to keep the state

Comment: I made edits per your suggestion?  Why did it work?  I added the code change.  Please post as an answer.